# Is there a trick for distributing a quantity produced in several orders?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

The goal is to honor the orders, and to know the delivery dates, but an order can be delivered in several times.
So I have to assign my production runs (even possibly parts of production runs) to orders (known values). For example my book orders per ProductNr:

```
orders = {
0 : [50,45,65], #ProductNr:[QuantityOrder1, QuantityOrder2...]
1 : [155,15,80,25] }
```

I am at the end of my program, before Maximize, with my production runs defined by OR-tools variables and stored in list, a run = One Product , a quantity , a day of production(link from NewIntervalVar)

```
[ProductNr(0,4),Quantity(1,200],Day(1,20)]
list_production =
[[Produit 0,30,1],
[Produit 1,100,1],
[Produit 1,90,2],
[Produit 0,40,2],
[Produit 0,60,3],
[Produit 1,40,3],
Produit 1,35,3]]
```

This list contains different NrProducts but totally out of order, the scenario prevents me from sorting/storing from the start by NrProduct.
On the other hand, what is certain is that the variable Day, is >= to the preceding (with same NrProduct) and <= to the next in the list (with same NrProduct).

Explanation of what I want:

For example if I have this order book order `{0 : [50,45,65],1 : [155,15,80,25] }` ,
whatever the quantity of the 1st production run on ProductNr "0", the quantity must be assigned to the first order: 50.
If there are missing quantities, the next production run will complete .. until reaching 50.

The goal is that in the end OR-tools sends me back for each order, what are the production runs (and therefore the dates link) which made it possible to complete the order and in what quantities.

Here is an illustrated example, with reservoirs representing orders:

[image]

Are there any tricks or functions that can handle this?

Thank you in advance, :)

Comment: do you need optimization ? You can waterfill one order at a time in your buckets?

Comment: Actually, I optimize the production schedule on the overall profitability of the monthly schedule, and the profitability is linked to the day of delivery (possible delays) of the different volumes to honor the orders : Or-Tools must know which quantities from which production run allow each order to be fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

If you can split demands arbitrarily across production units, you do not need to distinguish machines. Just have cumulative constraints with the combined capacities of all production units of the same type. This way, splitting is just ignored, and you can decide when/what to produce.

Once this is optimised, you can fix all the dates, all compute the splits to maximise affinity in a different optimisation model.

For info, the cumulative constraint is described [here](https://sofdem.github.io/gccat/gccat/Ccumulative.html):

It is used in many CP-SAT examples, the simplest being [the gate scheduling problem](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/gate_scheduling_sat.py)

Comment: In my illustrated example, each bucket corresponds to a quantity that a customer has ordered, the goal is to pick up the (part of) volumes in the production runs (make by only one machine) to fulfill the quantity of the order (and then of the others orders) as quickly as possible (delays will have an impact on overall profitability maximized).
If that's what you understood, I'm having trouble imagining this part of the model with this AddCumulative constraint to handle this. thanks Laurent.

Comment: how can I control whether my production (capacity) has made it possible to fill my order (demand) without forcing the model to oblige this, because in my model delays on orders are unfortunately inevitable, thank you.